# Can I filter out duplicates within an array list using hashset in Java without distorting the order of the array?

Tags: java, hashset

I was wondering how I could return an array list in Java but filter out any duplicates that come from my object? I've heard the best way to do this is by using a hashset is this true or is there a better implementation? The reason I am skeptical about using hashset is I have heard it distorts the order of the array which is not what I want.

Comment: Why not just use a `HashSet` in the first place?

Comment: I was wondering if there was any better implementation other than hashset as I believe in hashset it distorts the order of the array? @CKing

Comment: Fair enough. Use a `LinkedHashSet`. It does not allow duplicates and maintains insertion order.

Comment: Brilliant that's what I was looking for :) can you post it as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer :) @CKing

Comment: Done. However, I strongly feel that you should be trying out some code samples and going through the Java doc as well..

Comment: Yes thanks @CKing the reason I asked is I need to knock up a prototype tree structured web page so was gathering opinions for the cleanest and most efficient way of filtering out duplicates from my database. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are are looking for is a `Collection` that maintains insertion order and does not allow duplicates.

Thankfully, there is one available in the form of a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)